# How to use Gmail API in TypeScript (Angular latest version)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, gmail-api

I am building my Ionic app with Angular framework (latest version). And I want to send email from my app using Gmail API. I tried to use Google guide to get started but they have code in JavaScript (node.js). Even though vanilla JavaScript should work in TypeScript, it didn't work on my case.

So how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: *it didn't work on my case*. Please show what didn't work.

Comment: You should do this kind of staff in backend . If you send it from frondend how can you hide your apikey, your information of email ? People can see information in network in in developer console . your requests, your parameters etc.

Comment: Note that JavaScript code written for Node.js may not work in the browser. They have a [Browser quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) that is likely more on target than the one for Node.js.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Thank you. This really helps!

Comment: @pc_coder - You are right. Do you think if I will rebuild my web app with capacitor , someone might get access to the API key and email information?

Comment: @MichaelD - do you want me to send my code? Because I didn't get any errors in browser, it just didn't showup